# TypeError: path must be a string with commander

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I want to read a file with commander:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs')
var program = require('commander')

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .usage('<keywords>')
  .parse(process.argv)

if(!program.args.length) {
  program.help()
} else {
  var filename = program.args

  console.log('keys: ' + filename)

  fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(data)
  })
}

$ ./m2k.js test.txt
```

However, I get the this error:

```
fs.js:430
  binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
          ^
TypeError: path must be a string
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I have a file called `test.txt` in the same folder as `m2k.js`.)

Answer (score 6):

If you print the type of `program.args` or the `program.args` itself, you will know that its an Array.

```
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(program.args), program.args);
// [object Array] [ 'test.txt' ]
```

So, you need to use the correct index to be used like this

```
var filename = program.args[0];
```

I think the result of `console.log('keys: ' + filename)` is not helping you much. It is because when you use `+` operator, it will try to convert the `filename` object to a string and the String array converted to a string normally just has comma separated strings. You can check that like this

```
console.log(['a'].toString(), ['a', 'b'].toString());
// a a,b
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `filename` is actually an array of all arguments passed to your application.

add a `console.log(program.args)` to your code to see its contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
var filename = program.args;
```

The type of filename is a string object and not a string literal, because

```
typeof filename === 'object'  // true
typeod filename === 'string'  // false
```

simply do this to resolve that problem:

```
var filename = String(program.args);
```

because

```
new String(arg); //creates a new instance of the String object
```

and

```
process.argv // is an array of String objects not literals
```

while

```
String(arg); // tries to turn all objects into a string literal
```